# Converting signal to frequency domain then back to time domain - noise issue

Tags: matlab, fft, fourier-transform, frequency-response, time-domain

I am trying to convert a signal into frequency domain using fft then construct a time domain signal (with any length) from the frequency response. With my matlab code, it works fine when there is no noise but there is a weird behaviour when noise is introduced in to the signal.

So let's first look at the case when there is no noise.

```
clear
Fs = 100;          % Frequency (Hz)
dt = 1/Fs;         % Sampling Time (s)
Tsim_original = 3; % 3 seconds of original data
t = (0:dt:Tsim_original-dt)';     % Time array
signal = sin(2*pi*2*t) + 2 * sin(2*pi*3*t);    % Original signal

% Compute FFT - I'm using Matlab's example on their FFT page
Y = fft(signal);
L = length(signal);
P2 = abs(Y/L);
P1 = P2(1:floor(L/2)+1);
P1(2:end-1) = 2*P1(2:end-1);
f = (Fs*(0:(L/2))/L)';

figure(1)
clf
stem(f, P1, 'Marker', 'none')
hold on
grid on
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('|P1(f)|')


Tsim = 10;    % Time of constructed signal - I'm using longer time here, will be important later
signal2 = zeros(ceil(Tsim/dt), 1);          % Predefine constructed signal array
t2 = linspace(0, Tsim, length(signal2))';   % Time array

% Construct signal from FFT
% Loop through all the frequencies and add them to gether
for kk = 1 : length(f)
    if f(kk) > 0   % Ignore 0 Hz 
        temp = P1(kk) * sin(2*pi*f(kk)*t2);
        signal2 = signal2 + temp;
    end
end

figure(2)
clf
plot(t, signal)
hold on
grid on
plot(t2, signal2, '--')
legend('Original Signal', 'Constructed Signal')
xlabel('Time (s)')
```

So this works fine and the constructed signal pretty much looks identical to the original signal. The FFT also looks good, with correct frequency and amplitude.

[image]

Here's where the problem is. If I add some noise into the signal

```
signal = sin(2*pi*2*t) + 2 * sin(2*pi*3*t) + randn(length(t), 1);    % Original signal
```

The resulting signal has weird peaks happening every 3 seconds (and at the start), which is equivalent to the length of the original signal. If I change the length of the original signal to a different number, the frequency of the peaks also change accordingly. For example, if I change the the original signal to be 5 seconds long, the constructed signal has a peak every 5 seconds also.

I need the constructed signal to look like the figure below but without the peaks every X seconds. Note that I do not want to filter the noise, but rather I want to keep the noise.

So my questions are:

- What is the cause of these peaks? Am I doing something wrong?
- Is there a better way to reconstruct the time domain signal (with any length)?
- I understand matlab has the `ifft` function available already, but I am not sure how to get it to work with the absolute power `P1` of the frequency response. I kind of have to keep this FFT format as it's already in other parts of the code.

[image]

When zoomed in, the peak looks like this
[image]

Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

Lot's of things are questionable here

1. You are discarding the phase of the  Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT)
2. You don't do a complete inverse DFT, but instead just do a weighted sum of sine waves. That's equivalent of hard-wring the phase of the DFT to 90 degrees.
3. Extending by using a longer inverse DFT is equivalent to doing a periodic extension. Doing a long inverse DFT is very inefficient.
4. Your inverse FFT sample rate is slightly off due to incorrect use of `linspace()`. The check the spacing of your time axis.

The peak is due to you discarding the phase. The spectrum of Noise from `randn()` is mostly white, i.e. same magnitude at all frequencies but it has a random phase. By making all the phases the same, you create basically the DFT of a unit impulse which creates a peak in the inverse DFT

Comment: Could you please suggest what I can do to fix this? I have tried adding random phase shift to all the frequencies, but I still get the same peaks anyway unfortunately.

Comment: Just use the original phase and do a complete inverse DFT. That reconstructs the original signal

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in the beginning, you are trying to reconstruct a «sine only signal» from FFT magnitude and a sine only set of basis functions - with success.

Later on, when you add noise, you have a component that cannot be described by only sines, you need a set of cosines (or the complex exponensial) to describe that signal. Thus your method fails.

Fitting sines to the DFT in order to extrapolate a periodic signal is interesting, but it is limited to perfectly periodic signals and a DFT of exactly that period (or a multiple thereof). If you can accept such restrictions, it seems easier to just «copy and paste» the time domain snippet repeatedly, as in various PSOLA-esque methods?

Comment: That's pretty much what I have been doing. Manually chopping off the parts where I don't want then copy/paste the part I want. However, I prefer to not do this as I will get more data with different size and sampling rate in the future.

Comment: If you are manually identifying the periodicity today, you will have to do the same job with an FFT based solution. Unless you develop a method to identify periodicity automatically, but then you could use that method for time domain extrapolation too?